Want to create a button to show answer and hide answer
I want to create a webpage like this one..
https://www.placementpreparation.io/quantitative-aptitude/average/questions-and-answers/
I am creating website in WordPress using divi builder. I have tried following ajax code to display only a section of a webpage from different web page on button click..
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 

<head> 
    <script src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <h2 style="color: green;"> 
        just trial
    </h2> 
    <h3> 
        fetch only sections of specific HTML areas 
        from an external page using AJAX 
    </h3> 

    <button onclick="event_occur()"> 
        Click Here 
    </button><br><br> 

    <h3>External.html page</h3> 
    <div id="display"
        style="border: 1px solid black; 
                width:max-content; 
                padding:0.5rem"> 
        fetched Content will display here. 
    </div> 

    <script> 
        event_occur = () => { 
            // Load the Section with .first class and display 
            $("#display").load("index.html .first"); 
        }; 
    </script> 
</body> 

</html>

And the index.html page is as below...
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 

<head> 
    <title>webpage from wherer content is loaded</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <section class="first"> 
        <h3> 
            Index.html - Section - class = "first" 
        </h3> 
        <h2 style="color: green;"> 
            content from here will be loaded 
        </h2> 
        <h3>Web Development</h3> 
        <ul> 
            <li>HTML</li> 
            <li>CSS</li> 
            <li>JAVA SCRIPT</li> 
            <li>JQUERY</li> 
        </ul> 
    </section> 

    <section class="second"> 
        <h2 style="color: green;"> 
            this will not load 
        </h2> 
        <h3>Machine Learning</h3> 
        <ul> 
            <li>Python</li> 
        </ul> 
    </section> 

    <section class="third"> 
        <h2 style="color: green;"> 
            this will not load
        </h2> 
        <h3>Courses</h3> 
        <ul> 
            <li>Interview Preparation</li> 
            <li>DSA</li> 
            <li>DBMS</li> 
        </ul> 
    </section> 
</body> 

</html>

When I click on button click here then the desired section of the web page load. It works fine.
Now I want that at the same time text of click here button changes to hide answer and a new button is created automatically at the end of displayed answer. How to write code for hide answer button

What does console shows? May be some Cors error?
